# How to solve "Key not valid for use in specified state" error when using Azure ACS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, x509, acs

I'm attempting to get OpenID authentication to work in my Azure ASP.NET MVC 3 application and have followed the steps in the [MVC 3 Custom Login Sample](http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC3%20Custom%20Login&referringTitle=Samples) to do so. Everything works fine in the development environment but not when deployed to the Azure platform.

The first issue started with authentication causing the error **"Key not valid for use in specified state"**. The [discussion here](http://acs.codeplex.com/discussions/245441) states that the application needs to be configured to use RsaEncryptionCookieTransform instead of DPAPI which is the default. To try and solve this I added the code for `OnServiceConfigurationCreated` described [on Alik Levin's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2011/03/19/windows-azure-web-role-asp-net-application-federated-authentication-using-appfabric-access-control-service-acs-v2-part-2.aspx) but didn't go any further as it describes setting up a self-signed certificate in development (which as mentioned hasn't been necessary), not in Azure.

Instead of that approach, I tried to use the X.509 certificate already in Azure. I found the thumbprint under Windows Azure Management > Access Control Service > Relying Party Applications > (My Application Name) > Token Signing Certificates > Used for Service Namespace (X.509 Certificate). I then added this reference to the web.config:

```
<serviceCertificate>
    <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="8A417..." />
</serviceCertificate>
```

Now I receive a configuration error on application startup:

```
ID1024: The configuration property value is not valid.
Property name: 'certificateReference'
Error: 'ID1025: Cannot find a unique certificate that matches the criteria.
StoreName: 'My'
StoreLocation: 'LocalMachine'
X509FindType: 'FindByThumbprint'
FindValue: '8A417...''
```

Do I actually need to change the encryption method to resolve the "Key not valid for use in specified state" error? If so, how can I use the X.509 certificate already in Azure to encrypt cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found (again) the article [Securing Windows Azure Web Role ASP.NET Web Application Using Access Control Service v2.0](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/securing-windows-azure-web-role-asp-net-web-application-using-access-control-service-v2-0.aspx). After reconfiguring the web.config and the "Relying Party Applications" section of the ACS Management Portal according to this article, I was able to get everything to work. Specifically I wanted only those controller actions decorated with `RequireAuthentication`, as shown in the ACS 2.0 sample [for this tutorial](http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC3%20Custom%20Login&referringTitle=Samples), to require the user to be logged in. This now works.

The only downside is that the entire app has to run in SSL for the user experience to be seamless. Otherwise the user is prompted for auth when running in HTTP, authenticated, and then dumped back to HTTP apparently not authenticated. However, switching over to the SSL endpoint, the user has been authenticated!

In development fabric this was working as I wanted, Stack Overflow style, where I was able to run everything in standard HTTP without using a certificate and authentication happened over SSL. However because of the RSA cookie requirement in Azure and need for a certificate this won't work in the cloud. (It would be great if dev fabric warned about this and other [common gotchas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966484.aspx#sec3).) I hope to revisit this at some point in the future.

In summary, I recommend you understand Windows Identity Foundation and how it applies to Azure before attempting anything beyond the provided samples. Some resources available at time of writing:

- [TechNet Wiki for Azure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/tags/Windows+Azure/default.aspx) (specifically articles about ACS and WIF)
- [ClaimsID (CodePlex)](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/)
- [ACS (CodePlex)](http://acs.codeplex.com)
- [Programming Windows Identity Foundation (book)](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Books.aspx?Id=14101)

Comment: I was running into the same issue you did, I followed the guides you posted but have a question for you. Were you redirected to Access Control every time you ran your project in Visual Studio. If so how did you get around it? And did your site visitors get redirect to the realm every time or is it only in the development environment.

Comment: @Bombcode It was too long ago for me to remember specifics, sorry. However I remember the behaviour of ACS was different depending on whether I ran in dev or on the Azure platform.

Comment: Alright, thanks Alex after further debugging I found out the issue. I denied all users. I've allowed all users now and have block certain areas of the site.

Answer (score 4):

The certificate you are referring to is the token signing cert used by ACS. You need a cert deployed in your web role so WIF can use it to encrypt the cookies (nothing to do with the token). You will have to add a cert in your Windows Azure deployment. (Service Configuration).

See sample #5 in http://claimsid.codeplex.com

If this is a proof of concept and you want to just run with all defaults. See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966484.aspx#sec3

You need to set "Load User Profile=true" so DPAPI will work. (This is probably what you have in your local machine).

Comment: After looking at the sample and reading more documentation on this Codeplex site, I understand more about this now. I created and uploaded the certificate [using these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432987.aspx). I no longer have an error, just the Sign In link does nothing on the Azure platform.

Comment: Glad to hear it was useful. Are you running in the local Azure emulator? (you should probably start there before deploying to the cloud) Where does the login link point to?

Comment: I had everything working in the local emulator without a certificate or any problems, it's only when deploying to Azure that I ran into all this trouble! I'm doing this as a proof of concept so may run out of time on it, but I'll try and revisit and get this part working.